# Can we Use Google's Ajax Proposal?

Tags: seo, google, google-search, ajax

In October 2009 on Google's blog ([see this link](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html)) there was a proposal presented to make ajax websites crawlable.

Does anyone know if this got past the proposal stage and is it safe to use the methods outlined in that blog post? It's been 18 months since so I'm guessing something's happened since then, but I can't find any more info about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. It was ready to be used when it was posted. I'm not sure if other search engines use it.

To be sure google does (before going through the work of setting it all up) setup a hidden link and see if google hits it ..

it works on twitter
https://twitter.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/username